# Setup MongoDB database in Docker-setup, and a user that can access it. Getting error: "MongoServerError: Authentication failed" over and over

Tags: mongodb, docker

I'm trying to setup a MongoDB docker container, with a user and a password so I can access it. I haven't used MongoDB a lot, but I find it peculiar how difficult this is. I might be missing something elementary.

This is my `docker-compose.yaml`-file:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    container_name: hercules-mongodb
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/data/db
      - ./scripts/init-mongo.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-mongo.js
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=myrootuser
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=myrootsecret
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    networks:
      - backend

networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  data:
    driver: local
```

And this is the `./scripts/init-mongo.js` that I believe the most in (but I've tried a bazillion versions):

```
db.createUser({
  user: 'myuser',
  pwd: 'mysecret',
  roles: [{ role: 'dbOwner', db: 'dev' }],
});
```

### The overarching problem

With this setup, I can't access the database, with a wide variety of errors (both via `mongosh` and DataGrip).

### Solution attempt 1: Access via `mongosh` (outside Docker container)

This is where I want to connect from. But with whatever auth-credentials I try to access the instance, then I get the error:

I can access it without authentication, like this: `mongosh "mongodb://localhost:27017"`

But then if I try to do anything, then I'm stopped by authentication anyway:

```
test> show dbs
MongoServerError: Command listDatabases requires authentication

test> use admin
switched to db admin

admin> show users
MongoServerError: Command usersInfo requires authentication
```

Here is a list of attempted `mongosh`-connections commands:

```
mongosh "mongodb://myuser:mysecret@localhost:27017"
mongosh "mongodb://myuser:mysecret@localhost:27017/dev"
mongosh "mongodb://myuser:mysecret@localhost:27017/dev?authSource=admin"
mongosh "mongodb://myuser:mysecret@localhost:27017?authSource=admin"
```

Then all give the error: `MongoServerError: Authentication failed.`

And if I `bash` into by docker container and do a `printenv`, then I can see my `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME` and `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD`.

### Solution attempt 2: Access via `mongosh` (from inside docker container)

I do this by doing a: `docker ps`. Get the container ID. Then do a: `docker exec -it DOCKER_CONTAINER_ID bash` and then try the same thing. But it's the same result as solution attempt 1.

### Solution attempt 3: Setup user manually

I do this, by removing these lines from `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=myrootuser
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=myrootsecret
```

... which I've read, makes the mongoDB start up without auth (I'm not entirely sure about this).

Then I access it without auth:

```
mongosh "mongo://localhost:27017"
```

And add the user manually:

```
use admin
db.createUser({
  user: 'myuser',
  pwd: 'mysecret',
  roles: [{ role: 'dbOwner', db: 'dev' }],
});
```

The user is added!
And I can now access the database like this:

```
mongosh "mongodb://myuser:mysecret@localhost:27017"
```

But weirdly still not like this (targetting the `dev`-database):

```
mongosh "mongodb://myuser:mysecret@localhost:27017/dev"
```

GRRRRRRRRRRRR!!!

And even if this worked, it wouldn't be a viable solution, since I need to be able to remove my docker container and set it up, without having to do all this footwork.

### Solution attempt 4: Connect via DataGrip

With all credential information in DataGrip (both: `User: myuser` and `User: myrootuser` I get this error:

```
DBMS: Mongo DB
Case sensitivity: plain=mixed, delimited=mixed
Driver: MongoDB JDBC Driver (ver. 1.18, JDBC4.2)
Effective version: UNKNOWN (ver. 0.0)

Ping: 504 ms (keep-alive query results in error)

com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential
{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='myuser', source='admin', 
password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}
Command failed with error 18 (AuthenticationFailed): 'Authentication failed.' 
on server localhost:27017. The full response is 
{"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "Authentication failed.", "code": 18, "codeName": "AuthenticationFailed"}.
```

**Useful finding:** When I try to connect, I can see my docker logs, that the container is reached. It outputs this:

```
hercules-mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-14T15:42:52.235+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"192.168.65.1:46533","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"28b7bd04-8a55-4381-b9e7-282b3afab24c"}},"connectionId":17,"connectionCount":8}}
hercules-mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-14T15:42:52.236+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"192.168.65.1:46534","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"8c013417-add4-432a-9674-c81cbf656542"}},"connectionId":18,"connectionCount":9}}
hercules-mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-14T15:42:52.244+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn18","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"192.168.65.1:46534","client":"conn18","doc":{"driver":{"name":"mongo-java-driver|sync","version":"4.7.1"},"os":{"type":"Darwin","name":"Mac OS X","architecture":"x86_64","version":"14.0"},"platform":"Java/JetBrains s.r.o./17.0.4+7-b469.53","application":{"name":"DataGrip"}}}}
hercules-mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-14T15:42:52.244+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn17","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"192.168.65.1:46533","client":"conn17","doc":{"driver":{"name":"mongo-java-driver|sync","version":"4.7.1"},"os":{"type":"Darwin","name":"Mac OS X","architecture":"x86_64","version":"14.0"},"platform":"Java/JetBrains s.r.o./17.0.4+7-b469.53","application":{"name":"DataGrip"}}}}
hercules-mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-14T15:42:52.287+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"192.168.65.1:46535","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"81319dd5-9556-4e38-a288-644dfc0e0a5b"}},"connectionId":19,"connectionCount":10}}
hercules-mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-14T15:42:52.293+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn19","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"192.168.65.1:46535","client":"conn19","doc":{"driver":{"name":"mongo-java-driver|sync","version":"4.7.1"},"os":{"type":"Darwin","name":"Mac OS X","architecture":"x86_64","version":"14.0"},"platform":"Java/JetBrains s.r.o./17.0.4+7-b469.53","application":{"name":"DataGrip"}}}}
hercules-mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-14T15:42:52.293+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":20251,   "ctx":"conn19","msg":"Supported SASL mechanisms requested for unknown user","attr":{"user":{"user":"myuser","db":"admin"}}}
hercules-mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-14T15:42:52.294+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":6788604, "ctx":"conn19","msg":"Auth metrics report","attr":{"metric":"acquireUser","micros":0}}
hercules-mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-14T15:42:52.294+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":5286307, "ctx":"conn19","msg":"Failed to authenticate","attr":{"client":"192.168.65.1:46535","isSpeculative":true,"isClusterMember":false,"mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-256","user":"myuser","db":"admin","error":"UserNotFound: Could not find user \"myuser\" for db \"admin\"","result":11,"metrics":{"conversation_duration":{"micros":619,"summary":{"0":{"step":1,"step_total":2,"duration_micros":592}}}},"extraInfo":{}}}
hercules-mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-14T15:42:52.300+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":6788604, "ctx":"conn19","msg":"Auth metrics report","attr":{"metric":"acquireUser","micros":0}}
hercules-mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-14T15:42:52.301+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":5286307, "ctx":"conn19","msg":"Failed to authenticate","attr":{"client":"192.168.65.1:46535","isSpeculative":false,"isClusterMember":false,"mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-1","user":"myuser","db":"admin","error":"UserNotFound: Could not find user \"myuser\" for db \"admin\"","result":11,"metrics":{"conversation_duration":{"micros":764,"summary":{"0":{"step":1,"step_total":2,"duration_micros":740}}}},"extraInfo":{}}}
hercules-mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-14T15:42:52.305+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn19","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"192.168.65.1:46535","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"81319dd5-9556-4e38-a288-644dfc0e0a5b"}},"connectionId":19,"connectionCount":9}}
hercules-mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-14T15:42:52.310+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":20883,   "ctx":"conn18","msg":"Interrupted operation as its client disconnected","attr":{"opId":4856}}
hercules-mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-14T15:42:52.311+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn18","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"192.168.65.1:46534","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"8c013417-add4-432a-9674-c81cbf656542"}},"connectionId":18,"connectionCount":8}}
```

And then waits about 5-10 seconds, and then outputs this:

```
hercules-mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-14T15:42:59.893+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"192.168.65.1:46536","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"f7f82453-b48b-48eb-8540-602a4d309758"}},"connectionId":20,"connectionCount":9}}
hercules-mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-14T15:42:59.894+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn20","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"192.168.65.1:46536","client":"conn20","doc":{"driver":{"name":"mongo-java-driver|sync","version":"4.7.1"},"os":{"type":"Darwin","name":"Mac OS X","architecture":"x86_64","version":"14.0"},"platform":"Java/JetBrains s.r.o./17.0.4+7-b469.53","application":{"name":"DataGrip"}}}}
hercules-mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-14T15:42:59.899+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"192.168.65.1:46537","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"aa26153a-f02a-4c6b-877d-7342b033f092"}},"connectionId":21,"connectionCount":10}}
hercules-mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-14T15:42:59.900+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn21","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"192.168.65.1:46537","client":"conn21","doc":{"driver":{"name":"mongo-java-driver|sync","version":"4.7.1"},"os":{"type":"Darwin","name":"Mac OS X","architecture":"x86_64","version":"14.0"},"platform":"Java/JetBrains s.r.o./17.0.4+7-b469.53","application":{"name":"DataGrip"}}}}
hercules-mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-14T15:42:59.901+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":20251,   "ctx":"conn21","msg":"Supported SASL mechanisms requested for unknown user","attr":{"user":{"user":"myuser","db":"admin"}}}
hercules-mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-14T15:42:59.901+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":6788604, "ctx":"conn21","msg":"Auth metrics report","attr":{"metric":"acquireUser","micros":0}}
hercules-mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-14T15:42:59.902+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":5286307, "ctx":"conn21","msg":"Failed to authenticate","attr":{"client":"192.168.65.1:46537","isSpeculative":true,"isClusterMember":false,"mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-256","user":"myuser","db":"admin","error":"UserNotFound: Could not find user \"myuser\" for db \"admin\"","result":11,"metrics":{"conversation_duration":{"micros":837,"summary":{"0":{"step":1,"step_total":2,"duration_micros":754}}}},"extraInfo":{}}}
hercules-mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-14T15:42:59.905+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":6788604, "ctx":"conn21","msg":"Auth metrics report","attr":{"metric":"acquireUser","micros":0}}
hercules-mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-14T15:42:59.906+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":5286307, "ctx":"conn21","msg":"Failed to authenticate","attr":{"client":"192.168.65.1:46537","isSpeculative":false,"isClusterMember":false,"mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-1","user":"myuser","db":"admin","error":"UserNotFound: Could not find user \"myuser\" for db \"admin\"","result":11,"metrics":{"conversation_duration":{"micros":837,"summary":{"0":{"step":1,"step_total":2,"duration_micros":808}}}},"extraInfo":{}}}
hercules-mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-14T15:42:59.909+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn21","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"192.168.65.1:46537","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"aa26153a-f02a-4c6b-877d-7342b033f092"}},"connectionId":21,"connectionCount":9}}
hercules-mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-14T15:42:59.909+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":20883,   "ctx":"conn20","msg":"Interrupted operation as its client disconnected","attr":{"opId":4959}}
hercules-mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-14T15:42:59.910+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn20","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"192.168.65.1:46536","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"f7f82453-b48b-48eb-8540-602a4d309758"}},"connectionId":20,"connectionCount":8}}
hercules-mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-14T15:43:00.411+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"192.168.65.1:46538","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"3e48c376-9251-4188-9d4b-3121151fbb29"}},"connectionId":22,"connectionCount":9}}
hercules-mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-14T15:43:00.411+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn22","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"192.168.65.1:46538","client":"conn22","doc":{"driver":{"name":"mongo-java-driver|sync","version":"4.7.1"},"os":{"type":"Darwin","name":"Mac OS X","architecture":"x86_64","version":"14.0"},"platform":"Java/JetBrains s.r.o./17.0.4+7-b469.53","application":{"name":"DataGrip"}}}}
hercules-mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-14T15:43:00.415+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"192.168.65.1:46539","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"9c756e38-43d8-40c2-8e53-65ebfb4e0c3f"}},"connectionId":23,"connectionCount":10}}
hercules-mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-14T15:43:00.416+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn23","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"192.168.65.1:46539","client":"conn23","doc":{"driver":{"name":"mongo-java-driver|sync","version":"4.7.1"},"os":{"type":"Darwin","name":"Mac OS X","architecture":"x86_64","version":"14.0"},"platform":"Java/JetBrains s.r.o./17.0.4+7-b469.53","application":{"name":"DataGrip"}}}}
hercules-mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-14T15:43:00.417+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":20251,   "ctx":"conn23","msg":"Supported SASL mechanisms requested for unknown user","attr":{"user":{"user":"myuser","db":"admin"}}}
hercules-mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-14T15:43:00.417+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":6788604, "ctx":"conn23","msg":"Auth metrics report","attr":{"metric":"acquireUser","micros":0}}
hercules-mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-14T15:43:00.418+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":5286307, "ctx":"conn23","msg":"Failed to authenticate","attr":{"client":"192.168.65.1:46539","isSpeculative":true,"isClusterMember":false,"mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-256","user":"myuser","db":"admin","error":"UserNotFound: Could not find user \"myuser\" for db \"admin\"","result":11,"metrics":{"conversation_duration":{"micros":885,"summary":{"0":{"step":1,"step_total":2,"duration_micros":853}}}},"extraInfo":{}}}
hercules-mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-14T15:43:00.421+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":6788604, "ctx":"conn23","msg":"Auth metrics report","attr":{"metric":"acquireUser","micros":0}}
hercules-mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-14T15:43:00.422+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":5286307, "ctx":"conn23","msg":"Failed to authenticate","attr":{"client":"192.168.65.1:46539","isSpeculative":false,"isClusterMember":false,"mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-1","user":"myuser","db":"admin","error":"UserNotFound: Could not find user \"myuser\" for db \"admin\"","result":11,"metrics":{"conversation_duration":{"micros":1166,"summary":{"0":{"step":1,"step_total":2,"duration_micros":1122}}}},"extraInfo":{}}}
hercules-mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-14T15:43:00.425+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn23","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"192.168.65.1:46539","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"9c756e38-43d8-40c2-8e53-65ebfb4e0c3f"}},"connectionId":23,"connectionCount":9}}
hercules-mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-14T15:43:00.425+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":20883,   "ctx":"conn22","msg":"Interrupted operation as its client disconnected","attr":{"opId":4973}}
hercules-mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-14T15:43:00.426+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn22","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"192.168.65.1:46538","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"3e48c376-9251-4188-9d4b-3121151fbb29"}},"connectionId":22,"connectionCount":8}}
hercules-mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-14T15:43:00.931+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"192.168.65.1:46540","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"f1198ea4-d688-4aa3-8f28-e29224c2411d"}},"connectionId":24,"connectionCount":9}}
hercules-mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-14T15:43:00.931+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn24","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"192.168.65.1:46540","client":"conn24","doc":{"driver":{"name":"mongo-java-driver|sync","version":"4.7.1"},"os":{"type":"Darwin","name":"Mac OS X","architecture":"x86_64","version":"14.0"},"platform":"Java/JetBrains s.r.o./17.0.4+7-b469.53","application":{"name":"DataGrip"}}}}
hercules-mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-14T15:43:00.935+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"192.168.65.1:46541","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"52fcb8a2-18cb-476e-897c-e01fa54b4a47"}},"connectionId":25,"connectionCount":10}}
hercules-mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-14T15:43:00.936+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn25","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"192.168.65.1:46541","client":"conn25","doc":{"driver":{"name":"mongo-java-driver|sync","version":"4.7.1"},"os":{"type":"Darwin","name":"Mac OS X","architecture":"x86_64","version":"14.0"},"platform":"Java/JetBrains s.r.o./17.0.4+7-b469.53","application":{"name":"DataGrip"}}}}
hercules-mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-14T15:43:00.937+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":20251,   "ctx":"conn25","msg":"Supported SASL mechanisms requested for unknown user","attr":{"user":{"user":"myuser","db":"admin"}}}
hercules-mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-14T15:43:00.937+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":6788604, "ctx":"conn25","msg":"Auth metrics report","attr":{"metric":"acquireUser","micros":0}}
hercules-mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-14T15:43:00.938+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":5286307, "ctx":"conn25","msg":"Failed to authenticate","attr":{"client":"192.168.65.1:46541","isSpeculative":true,"isClusterMember":false,"mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-256","user":"myuser","db":"admin","error":"UserNotFound: Could not find user \"myuser\" for db \"admin\"","result":11,"metrics":{"conversation_duration":{"micros":811,"summary":{"0":{"step":1,"step_total":2,"duration_micros":788}}}},"extraInfo":{}}}
hercules-mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-14T15:43:00.940+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":6788604, "ctx":"conn25","msg":"Auth metrics report","attr":{"metric":"acquireUser","micros":0}}
hercules-mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-14T15:43:00.941+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":5286307, "ctx":"conn25","msg":"Failed to authenticate","attr":{"client":"192.168.65.1:46541","isSpeculative":false,"isClusterMember":false,"mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-1","user":"myuser","db":"admin","error":"UserNotFound: Could not find user \"myuser\" for db \"admin\"","result":11,"metrics":{"conversation_duration":{"micros":869,"summary":{"0":{"step":1,"step_total":2,"duration_micros":839}}}},"extraInfo":{}}}
hercules-mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-14T15:43:00.943+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn25","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"192.168.65.1:46541","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"52fcb8a2-18cb-476e-897c-e01fa54b4a47"}},"connectionId":25,"connectionCount":9}}
hercules-mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-14T15:43:00.944+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":20883,   "ctx":"conn24","msg":"Interrupted operation as its client disconnected","attr":{"opId":4987}}
hercules-mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-14T15:43:00.944+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn24","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"192.168.65.1:46540","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"f1198ea4-d688-4aa3-8f28-e29224c2411d"}},"connectionId":24,"connectionCount":8}}
hercules-mongodb  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-14T15:43:00.952+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn17","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"192.168.65.1:46533","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"28b7bd04-8a55-4381-b9e7-282b3afab24c"}},"connectionId":17,"connectionCount":7}}
```

So it can reach the Docker-container. But there is something off with my MongoDB authentication (obviously).

Comment: Regarding authentication have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470 Another note, when you enable authentication then authentication becomes active at the moment when you create the first admin user (i.e a user with `userAdminAnyDatabase` and `readWriteAnyDatabase` roles granted). As long as such admin user does not exist, authentication is not active!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself. It was a mix of several things.

Wernfried-domscheit's competent words was a HUGE help, helping me not to go further into a wrong direction. <3

I had come across [Wernfried Domscheit's answer to a different post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470) previously, which had helped a bit. But studying it extra carefully, helped me further.

### The big moment (mounting of docker volumes)

As you can see in my `docker-compose.yaml`-file, I mounted the volumes outside the container like this:

```
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/data/db
```

Which means that when I do a `docker-compose down` or a `docker-compose down --volumes` (to also remove connected volumes), then my database would continue to exist, since it lived outside the container.

This lead me far astray, since my manually created users and databases continued to be there after I thought I had 'reset the entire system'.

So I changed it to this:

```
    volumes:
      - data:/data/db
```

... to use the defined volume in the bottom. Which is removed when you do a `docker-compose down --volumes`. Making it easy to 'start over completely'.

That was the BIG finding.

After that, then Wernfried's post helped me understand how users and databases are created.

I then changes my init-script: `./scripts/init-mongo.js` to be like this:

```
db = db.getSiblingDB('admin');

db.createUser({
  user: 'myuser',
  pwd: 'mysecret',
  roles: [
    { role: 'userAdminAnyDatabase', db: 'admin' },
    { role: 'readWriteAnyDatabase', db: 'admin' },
  ],
});
```

Now I could create a root-user like that.

With that root user I could create further database and/or users.